# Вызвать переменную из другого класса

Tags: c#

Всем доброго!!! Пытаюсь программировать на С#, но уперся уже несколько дней - не могу вызвать переменную из другого ("а") из другого класса ("Class1').

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            

            new Class1();

            double b = Class1.a;


            Console.WriteLine("a = {0}", b);

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    string command = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (command == "stop")
                    {
                        
                        break;
                    }


                }
                catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
                {
                    

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Класс, от которого надо взять значение переменной "а" максимально упрощен

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    

   public class Class1
    {
      public double  a = 179;
    }
}
```

Пробовал гуглить, яндексить и т. д. - не помогло.

Comment: на всякий случай, для облегчения поиска - `a` - это не переменная (локальные переменные в C# - это значения, которые вы объявляете внутри методов). `a` - это поле (field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в этой строке:

```
new Class1();
```

Здесь Вы создаете класс анонимно и соответственно далее уже не можете к нему обращаться.
Нужно делать так:

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1();
double b = class1.a;
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Кое что понял. Теперь буду дальше заниматься своей программой: эта была для облегчения восприятия вопроса.

Comment: Это не анонимно. Это просто ссылка на созданный экземпляр не запоминается.

Comment: @VlaD, Да, действительно. Путаюсь в терминологии.